# Python TypeError, one argument six given.

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

Alright I am trying to gather x, y coordinates as you all know and I am working on the save feature to save the x, y's to a text file. here is what I got

```
x1 = raw_input("What is x1: ")
y1 = raw_input("What is y1: ")
x2 = raw_input("what is x2: ")
y2 = raw_input("what is y2: ")
outFile = open("c:\\users\zilvarael\Desktop\coord_man.txt", "wt")
outFile.write("Coordinate file: \n", x1, y1, "\n", x2, y2)
```

Here is the error I am facing:

```
    outFile.write("Coordinate file: \n", x1, y1, "\n", x2, y2)
    TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.write` only takes one argument, format the string first:

```
outFile.write("Coordinate file: \n {} {} \n {} {}".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```